# Using IPFS for CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipfs

I am attempting to load a css stylesheet from the following link...
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdun4VYeqRJtisjDxLoRMRj2aTY9skWkVyy4BfhkDjYuC

I have tried adding this link tag to both my main and head tags.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdun4VYeqRJtisjDxLoRMRj2aTY9skWkVyy4BfhkDjYuC">
```

I've also tried adding a style tag like this

```
var cssLink = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdun4VYeqRJtisjDxLoRMRj2aTY9skWkVyy4BfhkDjYuC";
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = "@import url("+cssLink+")";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Neither work, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: In DevTools what's the error?

Comment: No error, just the css is not being applied.  My profile_pic doesn't have a width of 100px

Comment: Can you put some sort of debugging rule, such as "color: red" to root of your stylesheet?  We can  quickly test if that applies

Comment: I can get it to apply when I link to it locally, but using the ipfs link doesn't work

Comment: This is so weird. The stylesheet is being loaded correctly, as seen in the Sources tab of the devtools. If you edit the source file slightly, the CSS takes effect.

Comment: The only  thing I can see in console is that response header from ipfs is  `text/plain` and not `text/css`. Maybe this is the issue

Comment: Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I fixed it like this  
`const cssLink = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/"+css;`
`const cssText = await fetch(cssLink).then(res => res.text());`
`const cssBlob = new Blob([cssText], {type:"text/css"});`
`const cssURL = URL.createObjectURL(cssBlob);`
but I'm wondering if there is a better way

Comment: I think the only way is to correctly serve CSS, with appropriate headers. Your workaround does the job, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPFS returns the file as `text/plain`. To get it to `text/css` I did

```
const cssLink = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdun4VYeqRJtisjDxLoRMRj2aTY9skWkVyy4BfhkDjYuC";
const cssText = await fetch(cssLink).then(res => res.text());
const cssBlob = new Blob([cssText], {type:"text/css"});
const cssURL = URL.createObjectURL(cssBlob);
const cssAtts = {"rel":"stylesheet", "type":"text/css", "href":cssURL, "key":"css"}
React.createElement("link",cssAtts,null);
```

I'm new to JavaScript so if there is an even better way to do this, I'm curious to learn more.

Comment: Interesting, good job